# Push-in refactor of a roo generated controller raises "No crosscutting model available. Rebuild project"

Tags: aspectj, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

This project compiles without error and runs fine.  I have run "Project..Clean" on it, as well as "Maven..Update project" and "mvn clean install".  After each of these steps, I still get the same refactoring error.

I also selected "Spring tools..Enable Spring Aspects tooling" just for kicks.

I also tried disabling and re-enabling JDT Weaving, and also tried the "Index Now" option.

What am I missing to be able to refactor the roo controller?

STS Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE

aspectjrt-1.7.0.RC1
aspectjweaver-1.7.0.RC1

Answer (score 2):

I switched the maven configuration to use the embedded version instead of the external command, and a rebuild allows be to refactor now.  I discovered by using the external maven, the crosscutting model is not built in the Eclipse environment.

Background:  Due to an previous problem with maven, it was suggested to use the external version, which resolved THAT problem of not being able to be compiled inside of Eclipse. Apparently that issue is gone, as the project now builds with the embedded maven.

Answer (score -1):

Some hints to resolve the problem:

- right click > disable maven nature, then go to the system directory of your project, do an `mvn eclipse:clean`, return to eclipse, right click, configure > convert to maven project.
- verify if you have project > build automatically is checked.
- do a project > clean, maybe this is the final step you missed.

Comment: It has nothing with the problem to do.